# iOs build fails with FacebookLogin package

Tags: ios, facebook, flutter

I'm currently using the [Facebook Login package for Flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_facebook_login) for a Flutter app that I'm developing and I'm having problems with building it in iOs.

I've followed all the steps in the guide and works fine in Android but when I try to run it in iOs simulator I have this output

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone X in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Starting Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            3.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/AppEvents/FBSDKPaymentObserver.m:23:
    In file included from /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/AppEvents/FBSDKAppEvents+Internal.h:19:
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.h:33:19: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
    FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSNotificationName const FBSDKAppEventsLoggingResultNotification;
                      ^
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.h:33:19: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
    FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSNotificationName const FBSDKAppEventsLoggingResultNotification;
                      ^
                                         _Nullable
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.h:33:19: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
    FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSNotificationName const FBSDKAppEventsLoggingResultNotification;
                      ^
                                         _Nonnull
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.h:700:13: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
    + (NSString *)getUserData;
                ^
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.h:700:13: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
    + (NSString *)getUserData;
                ^
                 _Nullable
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.h:700:13: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
    + (NSString *)getUserData;
                ^
                 _Nonnull
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.h:714:44: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
    + (void)updateUserProperties:(NSDictionary *)properties handler:(FBSDKGraphRequestHandler)handler;
                                               ^
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.h:714:44: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
    + (void)updateUserProperties:(NSDictionary *)properties handler:(FBSDKGraphRequestHandler)handler;
                                               ^
                                                _Nullable
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.h:714:44: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
    + (void)updateUserProperties:(NSDictionary *)properties handler:(FBSDKGraphRequestHandler)handler;
                                               ^
                                                _Nonnull
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.h:714:66: warning: block pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
    + (void)updateUserProperties:(NSDictionary *)properties handler:(FBSDKGraphRequestHandler)handler;
                                                                     ^
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.h:714:66: note: insert '_Nullable' if the block pointer may be null
    + (void)updateUserProperties:(NSDictionary *)properties handler:(FBSDKGraphRequestHandler)handler;
                                                                     ^
                                                                                              _Nullable 
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.h:714:66: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the block pointer should never be null
    + (void)updateUserProperties:(NSDictionary *)properties handler:(FBSDKGraphRequestHandler)handler;
                                                                     ^
                                                                                              _Nonnull 
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.h:726:43: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
    + (void)augmentHybridWKWebView:(WKWebView *)webView;
                                              ^
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.h:726:43: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
    + (void)augmentHybridWKWebView:(WKWebView *)webView;
                                              ^
                                               _Nullable
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.h:726:43: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
    + (void)augmentHybridWKWebView:(WKWebView *)webView;
                                              ^
                                               _Nonnull
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/AppEvents/FBSDKPaymentObserver.m:242:38: error: property 'subscriptionPeriod' not found on object of type 'SKProduct *'
          BOOL isSubscription = (product.subscriptionPeriod != nil) && ((unsigned long)product.subscriptionPeriod.numberOfUnits > 0);
                                         ^
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/AppEvents/FBSDKPaymentObserver.m:242:92: error: property 'subscriptionPeriod' not found on object of type 'SKProduct *'
          BOOL isSubscription = (product.subscriptionPeriod != nil) && ((unsigned long)product.subscriptionPeriod.numberOfUnits > 0);
                                                                                               ^
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/AppEvents/FBSDKPaymentObserver.m:248:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'SKProductSubscriptionPeriod'
            SKProductSubscriptionPeriod *period = product.subscriptionPeriod;
            ^
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/AppEvents/FBSDKPaymentObserver.m:248:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'period'
            SKProductSubscriptionPeriod *period = product.subscriptionPeriod;
                                         ^
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/AppEvents/FBSDKPaymentObserver.m:248:55: error: property 'subscriptionPeriod' not found on object of type 'SKProduct *'
            SKProductSubscriptionPeriod *period = product.subscriptionPeriod;
                                                          ^
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/AppEvents/FBSDKPaymentObserver.m:250:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'period'
            switch (period.unit) {
                    ^
    /Users/javier/Documents/Android_Studio_Projects/squat_app/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/AppEvents/FBSDKPaymentObserver.m:256:76: error: use of undeclared identifier 'period'
            NSString *p = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"P%lu%@", (unsigned long)period.numberOfUnits, unit];
                                                                               ^
    5 warnings and 7 errors generated.
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone X.
```

I did `flutter clean` and `pod update` in the ios folder but keeps crashing. I don't know what's happening and if it's more a package problem than mine.

Here's the output of my `flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.9.4, on Mac OS X 10.12.6 16G1036, locale en-ES)
    • Flutter version 0.9.4 at /Users/javier/Documents/flutter
    • Framework revision f37c235c32 (4 weeks ago), 2018-09-25 17:45:40 -0400
    • Engine revision 74625aed32
    • Dart version 2.1.0-dev.5.0.flutter-a2eb050044

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/javier/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 9.0, Build version 9A235
    • ios-deploy 1.9.2
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 29.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.5656
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[✓] Connected devices (2 available)
    • Mi A1    • 1f95603a0804                         • android-arm64 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)
    • iPhone X • 32CD2ECE-8C12-4F3A-B768-E1568B9754A7 • ios           • iOS 11.0 (simulator)
```

I'd appreciate if someone could help me finding the cause of this issue because I'm pretty lost right now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was my Xcode version. I updated to 9.2 and now it works fine.

Here's my Doctor output

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.9.4, on Mac OS X 10.12.6 16G1036, locale en-ES)
    • Flutter version 0.9.4 at /Users/javier/Documents/flutter
    • Framework revision f37c235c32 (4 weeks ago), 2018-09-25 17:45:40 -0400
    • Engine revision 74625aed32
    • Dart version 2.1.0-dev.5.0.flutter-a2eb050044

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/javier/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 9.0, Build version 9A235
    • ios-deploy 1.9.2
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 29.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.5656
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[✓] Connected devices (2 available)
    • Mi A1    • 1f95603a0804                         • android-arm64 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)
    • iPhone X • 32CD2ECE-8C12-4F3A-B768-E1568B9754A7 • ios           • iOS 11.0 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```